# MVC EF saving post type and customer type in one

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a type called `blogpost` with a property virtual reference to type `customer`.

```
public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
```

In my form I post the `blogpost` and `customer` data to a controller. All values are received. However when I use `SaveChanges` the `customer` data is not saved.

```
db.BlogPosts.Add(blog);
db.SaveChanges();
```

So I want the `blogpost` data to be saved to table `blogpost` (which works) but the customer table remains empty.

```
public ActionResult WriteBlog(Models.BlogPost blog, HttpPostedFileBase blogImage, HttpPostedFileBase blogLogo)
    {

db.BlogPosts.Add(blog);
db.SaveChanges();

return View();
}
```

Comment: Are you setting the CustomerId/Customer property to the blog ?

Comment: do you mean i first have to save the customer , get the newly added id and save that to the blogpost?

Comment: No. you do not need to. Can you show your full code of your HttpPost action method.

Comment: i have added the controller code. Removed the upload stuff

Comment: WHere in this code is the customer data being assigned?  This is your issue.

Comment: Yes that's the issue. Not sure how to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you are setting the `CustomerId`/`Customer` property value to the `BlogPost` entity object, It should save the customer without any problem. So i am assuming that your problem lies in your razor view and it is not sending the correct data back to the HttpPost action method.

It looks like you are using the entity class generated by entity framework directly in the view. This is generally not a good practice as now your view is tightly coupled to this entity. Ideally you should be using a view specific viewmodel class to transfer data from your view to your action method and there you will read the posted viewmodel object(created by MVC Modelbinding from form data) property values, create an entity object, set the property values and save it.

To start, create a viewmodel like this

```
public class CreatePostViewModel
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { set; get; }
    [Required]
    public string CustomerName { set; get; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase BlogImage { set; get; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase BlogLogo { set; get; }
}
```

Make your razorview strongly typed to this viewmodel

```
@model CreatePostViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Post", FormMethod.Post, 
                                                 new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))

{
    <label>Post title</label>    @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.Title)
    <label>Customer  </label>    @Html.TextBoxFor(s => s.CustomerName)
    <label>Blog Image</label>    <input type="file" name="BlogImage" />
    <label>Blog Logo </label>    <input type="file" name="BlogLogo"  />

    <input type="submit"/>
}
```

And in your HttpPost action method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreatePostViewModel model)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
     // To get the files, access model.BlogImage & model.BlogLogo properties  
     using(var db=new YourDbContext())
     {
       var customer = new Customer();
       customer.Name = model.CustomerName;
       //Set other property values as well

       var blog = new BlogPost();
       blog.Title = model.Title;
       blog.Customer = customer;
       //Set other property values as well

       db.Blogs.Add(blog);
       db.SaveChanges();
     }
   }
   return View(model);
}
```