# MVC Controller not working when using VIewModel with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing an MVC4 application with Angular JS and Entity Framework6.0. While saving data to DB its save only in One table. Actually it would be save into different table. Lets say Patient, PatientAddress, City,State etc.

**Using EF** so its creates Model Like this

```
    [GeneratedCodeAttribute("EF.Reverse.POCO.Generator", "2.17.0.0")]
    public partial class Patient
    {
        public int PatientId { get; set; } // PatientID (Primary key)
        public Guid? PatientGuid { get; set; } // PatientGUID
        public string FirstName { get; set; } // FirstName
        public string MiddleName { get; set; } // MiddleName
        public string LastName { get; set; } // LastName
        public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; } // DateOfBirth
        public int? Age { get; set; } // Age
        public int GenderId { get; set; } // GenderID
        public string Occupation { get; set; } // Occupation

        // Reverse navigation
        public virtual ICollection<PatientAddress> PatientAddresses { get; set; } // Many to many mapping
        public virtual ICollection<PatientAppointment> PatientAppointments { get; set; } // PatientAppointment.fk_PatientAppointment_Patient
        public virtual ICollection<PatientInsurance> PatientInsurances { get; set; } // Many to many mapping
        public virtual PatientEmergencyContact PatientEmergencyContact { get; set; } // PatientEmergencyContact.fk_PatientEmergencyContact_Patient

        // Foreign keys
        public virtual GenderMaster GenderMaster { get; set; } // fk_Patient_GenderMaster

        public Patient()
        {
            PatientGuid = System.Guid.NewGuid();
            PatientAddresses = new List<PatientAddress>();
            PatientAppointments = new List<PatientAppointment>();
            PatientInsurances = new List<PatientInsurance>();
            InitializePartial();
        }

        partial void InitializePartial();
    }

}
```

**AngularJS** 
Having **Controller.Js** here I get html form values

```
app.controller("PatientInfo", function ($scope, myService) {
    $scope.SavePatient = function () {
        debugger;
      //  alert("Red");
        var PatientInformation = {
            FirstName: $scope.Patient.FirstName,
            MiddleName: $scope.Patient.MiddleName,
            LastName: $scope.Patient.LastName,
            DOB: $scope.Patient.DOB,
            Age: $scope.Patient.Age,
            GenderId : $scope.Patient.GenderId,
            Occupation: $scope.Patient.Occupation,
            Address: $scope.PatientAddress.AddressPa,
            District: $scope.CityMaster.NameCm,
            State: $scope.StateMaster.NameSm,
            Pincode: $scope.PatientAddress.PinCodePa,
            PhoneNumber: $scope.PatientAddress.PhoneNumberPa,
            EmailID: $scope.PatientAddress.EmailID,
            ContactPersonName: $scope.ContactPersonName,
            ContactPersonRelation: $scope.ContactPersonRelation,
            ContactPersonAddress: $scope.ContactPersonAddress,
            ContactPersonEmail: $scope.ContactPersonEmail,
            ContactPersonPhoneNumber: $scope.ContactPersonPhoneNumber,
            InsuranceID: $scope.InsuranceID
        };
        var getData = myService.AddPatient(PatientInformation);
        getData.then(function (msg) {
            alert(msg.data);
        }, function () {
            alert('Error in adding record');
        });
    }
});
```

**Service.JS**: and here I pass above controller value to MVC Controller.

```
app.service("myService", function ($http) {
    this.AddPatient = function (PatientInformation) {
        debugger;
        var response = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "RegisterNewPatient/AddPatient",
            data: JSON.stringify(PatientInformation),
            dataType: "json"
        });
        return response;
    }
});
```

**RegisterNewPatientController.cs**

```
public class RegisterNewPatientController : Controller
    {
        HospitalTeamWebDeContext objHospitalTeamWebDeContext = new HospitalTeamWebDeContext();
        public ActionResult Index()
        { 
            return View("..//Patient/RegisterNewPatient");
        }

        public string AddPatient(Patient objPatient)
        {
            try
            {
                if (objPatient.GenderId == 0)
                {
                    objPatient.GenderId = 1;
                }

                objHospitalTeamWebDeContext.Patients.Add(objPatient);
                objHospitalTeamWebDeContext.SaveChanges();

            }
            catch
            {
            }
            finally
            {

            }
            return "Patient Saved.";
        }
    }
}
```

Here is above code.

Now It time to show you the o/p

[image]

But In controller.CS file I get an only Patient information but Pateint Address, Patient Emergency Contact are always blank.
[image]

I have tried lot of approach for it but it wont work.

Comment: try creating a different class then Patient  as PatientViewModel and create properties as your view model is returning, in the code its not able to directly bind `public virtual ICollection<PatientAddress> PatientAddresses` as with data coming from js.

Comment: I agree with Viplock ,  This is porpbably a binding issue with your entity class.  A better practice would be to use a View Model or DTO (A simple POCO C# object) with no virtuals that reflects your entity and it's propities.  Then use something like Automapper to repopulate this to your enitty models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Patient` entity class, `PatientAddresses` property is a collection of `PatientAddress` class. But looks like from your client side, you are sending a string value for the `PatientAddresses` property. You need to make sure you are sending a collection (Array).

```
var patientInformation = {
   FirstName : "Pritish",
   LastName  : "SomeNiceLastName",
   Age : 23,
   PatientAddresses : [{ AddressLine1 : "4201 State St", City : "Ann Arbor", Zip: 48103}] 

};
// Send this javascript object now.
```

Assuming your `PatientAddress` entity class looks like

```
public class PatientAddress
{
  public string AddressLine1 { set;get;}
  public string City { set;get;}
  public string Zip {set;get;}
}
```

Also, **It is not a good idea to use your Entity classes created by your ORM library in your UI layer**. That is more a tightly coupled solution. You should consider using view models/DTO's in your UI layer to make it a more loosely coupled solution which will allow you to easily switch your data access layer without impacting your UI code. Take a look [at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34275721/40521) to see how to use view specific view models in the UI layer, read that value and save that to the db.