# MVC 6 Razor View Model with Navigation properties

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have a Entity with a navigation property. My Create action has two model properties. Entity1 and Entity2 where Entity2 is a navigation property on Entity1.

The problem is that the view only binds 1 model. How to i get the navigation property (Entity2) to bind so I can create an new Entity1 and have Entity2 created at the same time.

Comment: Try to use a view model in your UI layer. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34273449/mvc-ef-saving-post-type-and-customer-type-in-one/34275721#34275721) is an example.

Comment: Can you post some more code? I don't understand your problem.